# Can SharePoint 2016 Farm be provisioned on a Kubernetes cluster or using Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, kubernetes, azure-devops

I am just shifting to container Orchestration and would like to know if a mid size SharePoint 2016 farm can be provisioned inside a highly available container orchestration platform called Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). Can we use Kubernetes cluster instead of VMs created on latest Windows Server 2016/2012 to provision SharePoint Farm? Since SharePoint is a highly resource consuming server application, scaling decision is a key to keep the Prod farm up and running within the containers. Containers are a better solution than highly scaled VMs but will it work for SharePoint? Please provide any pointers if anyone could.

Regards,
Manish

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You cannot run sharepoint in docker.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212904/can-an-on-prem-solution-of-sharepoint-2013-or-2016-be-hosted-in-a-docker-windows
[Active directory accounts inside a windows container (server 2016 TP5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677018/active-directory-accounts-inside-a-windows-container-server-2016-tp5)

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through the links you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint requires its servers and services to run using a specific Active Directory. There is no out-of-the box or easy solution for this. But you may refer to this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/containerstuff/create-a-container-with-active-directory-support) post from Microsoft regarding how to register a container with AD.